# Understanding and examples on Allen's interval algebra

Tags: intervals, algebra

I am new to algerba and trying to understand the following method for my research, can someone recommend a course or tutorial to explain.

Allen's Interval Algebra

Answer (score 0):

If you use the R programming language, I've written a package that faithfully implements Allen's Interval Algebra, which would allow you to interactively play with the ideas:

Related functions
https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/reference/index.html#allen-s-interval-algebra

Some useful docs
https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/reference/allen-relation-detect.html#allen-s-interval-algebra

A few examples:
https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/reference/allen-relation-detect.html#ref-examples

General introduction to the package:
https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/articles/ivs.html

Comment: Thank you, I will go through this. I would also like to understand the concept as well before I go in to examples. if you have any idea of a good explanation to the algortithm.

Comment: In that case, the original paper is the best resource: https://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/Documents/Allen-CACM1983.pdf